# how to build Programmerly control 3D Avatar or Character S

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I'm a student, I'm doing my final year project. It's for deaf students.

How can I create 3D human character?
How can I control that human characters movements via a vb or c# program 
such as when I'm type in a text box "Right hand" The 3D model shod raise his/her right hand.

Are there any suitable libs for my need?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are no libraries working on an abstraction level so high as you are describing.

I think you should look into some 3D game engines/libraries. I know that XNA is quite popular for C#. It is not as simple as importing a 3D model and telling it to raise its right hand though.

Comment: Dear All Thank you For Respond my question , Could i use flashCS4 OR CS5 Instead Of these 3d Libraries

Comment: I know you can do 3D in flash, but tbh i have no idea about how or if it is any good.

Answer (score 1):

i would look into XNA

start off with 2d then move onto 3D

there are some excellent videos here

http://www.XNATutorial.com

you should be able to skip most of the theory lessons

you may also want to check out the first tutorial here as well

http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment

whilst its not technically a game you are developing the theory is the same

Answer (score 0):

WPF is definetly the wrong approach for that because it has only a low performance if you use too complex models. It is also complicated to build 3D models in WPF.

As Yakyb and andvin said XNA would be a good choice.

Comment: Dear All Thank you For Respond my question , Could i use flashCS4 OR CS5 Instead Of these 3d Libraries